# Recyclerview, otifyItemChanged() and image loaded by Picasso

Tags: android, picasso, android-recyclerview

I have problem with Picasso cache (I think so). I created RecyclerView and RecyclerView.Adapter. A single item on the list contain ImageView. To this imageView I load image using Picasso library like this:

```
 public void onBindViewHolder(PageViewHolder holder, int position) {
    final int positionAdp = holder.getAdapterPosition();

    (new Picasso.Builder(mContext).addRequestHandler(new PageThumbRequestHandler(mPagesContainer.get()))
            .build())
            .load(PageThumbRequestHandler.REQUEST_SCHEME + "://" + mPages.get(positionAdp).mTag)
            .memoryPolicy(MemoryPolicy.NO_CACHE, MemoryPolicy.NO_STORE)
            .networkPolicy(NetworkPolicy.NO_CACHE)
            .into(holder.mThumbView);

    holder.mThumbView.setTag(mPages.get(positionAdp).mTag);
    holder.mThumbView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String tag = (String) v.getTag();
            mPageListener.onPageSelected(tag);
        }
    });
    holder.mLp.setText(Integer.toString(mPages.get(positionAdp).mLp));
}
```

When I update item I call notifyItemChanged method. On screen I see that updated item is flicking, so item is invalidate correctly. But new thumb is not display - i always get first loaded bitmap into ImageView.

Answer (score 0):

You should not use the `holder.getAdapterPosition()` for this, as the [RecyclerView JavaDoc states](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter.html):

> [...] you should only **use the position parameter while acquiring the related data item inside this method** and should not keep a copy of it. If you need the position of an item ***later*** on (e.g. in a click listener), use getAdapterPosition() which will have the updated adapter position.

So, do not use the `getAdapterPosition()` unless you are sure it will be executed asynchronously by unknown factors, such as user interaction (ie. inside a click or touch listener).

For the first load of the View Holder, use the `position` argument from the `onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position)` method, that will be the position of the data in the recycler's Adapter.